# Where does Visual Studio store data connection strings used in SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, vspackage

If you are familiar of using `SSDT tools in visual studio` to compare `database schema or data` then you might be noticed the below picture ...

[image: SSDT Connection setting box]

Due to my [visual studio add-in](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/530c546a-fdd3-4589-b2b2-e3c4aab13fba) work i need to provide end user these connection strings.. Can you please help me to find-out where these data connection string resides and how SSDT access them.. Any hints will be appreciated ..

**Note**:  I am not asking about server explorer data connection strings .. where they resides i already knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but it looks like it's stored in the registry. I used [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to get a look at what VS was doing when I added a new connection. I couldn't pinpoint from there what was happening because there was *so* much stuff. But I realized that it was hitting the registry a crap ton. So I searched the registry for one of my servers and eventually found a spot that looks good.

This is the registry path:
[image]

This is what they look like:
[image]

If that isn't it, I'll keep looking. But I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: Thanks man.. Yes this is where these connection strings are kept .. Now through .net i can show end users all saved connection string .. but the problem is connection strings value are encrypted .. Can you crack it?

Comment: @MoumitMondal Ah. Right. For dumb reason, I didn't consider that you wanted the actual connection string :P Well, at least we're one step further. The connection string doesn't look like it's encrypted in the traditional encryption. If it's truly encrypted, I don't think there'd be a way to decrypt it unless MS provides the hashes and what not. Or if they have a public decrypt method they use. But I'll try and see if there's anything that can be done. It might take a little time, though.